# как добавить gnu/make-цели на русском в список авто-дополнения?

Tags: bash, makefile, autocomplete, gnu

**предуведомление**: это перевод моего [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31636048/4827341).

*gnu/make* поддерживает и не-латинские идентификаторы (к примеру, цели) в *makefile*.

пример:

```
$ cat GNUmakefile
test:
  @echo "цель: $@"
тест:
  @echo "цель: $@"

$ make test тест
цель: test
цель: тест
```

но *bash-completion* в этом примере дополняет только одну цель — `test`:

"make " + <kbd>tab</kbd> → "make test".

как добавить русские имена целей в список, выдаваемый *bash-completion*-ом?

---

проверено в различных дистрибутивах (*debian* 5-8, *ubuntu* 12-15, *centos* 5-6, *mandriva* 2008, какая-то древняя *fedora*) с различными версиями *bash-completion*.

нужна поддержка этой возможности как минимум для свежей версии *bash-completion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**предуведомление**: это перевод моего [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31637332/4827341).

нашёл решение.

ошибка — в функции `_make_target_extract_script` из файла `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`, которая возвращает *sed*-скрипт, который содержит такую строку:

```
/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]/             d             # convention for hidden tgt
```

которая удаляет цели, начинающиеся (в том числе) и с не-латинского символа.

вот такое регулярное выражение, по-моему, подходит лучше (см. [эту информацию](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.7)):

```
/^[^[[:alnum:]]]/             d             # convention for hidden tgt
```

---

если нет возможности (или желания) исправлять `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/make`, то можно добавить в `~/.bashrc` такие, например, строки (основано на [этом ответе](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216806/110559)):

```
_completion_loader make
eval "$(type _make_target_extract_script | sed '1d;s/a-zA-Z0-9/[[:alnum:]]/')"
```

---

**обновление**

отправил разработчикам [сообщение об ошибке](https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315118&group_id=100114&atid=413095).